# laravel 5.4: list of input checked checkboxes

Tags: forms, laravel, for-loop, request

I have a form with a list of checkboxes with inputnames like `typedoc_1`, `typedoc_2`, `typedoc_3` etc..
How can I make a loop to check which numbers are checked? Normally I work with `Request (as $request->type_1)` in my controller. 
Thanks.

Comment: show what you have done so far, what do you want, explain with some code and what do you mean by `which numbers are checked`?? is it on controller or on view??

Answer (score 1):

// Blade

```
<input type="checkbox" checked name="typedoc[]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="typedoc[]" value="2"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="typedoc[]" value="3"/>
<input type="checkbox" checked name="typedoc[]" value="4"/>
```

// Controller

```
$selected = $request->typedoc; // [1,4]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input type="checkbox" name="typedoc[1]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="typedoc[2]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="typedoc[3]" value="1"/>
<input type="checkbox" name="typedoc[4]" value="1"/>
```

in your controller :

```
$typedocs = $request->typedoc;
foreach($typedocs as $key=> $value){
  if($value == 1) { ##here you can check your condition
   //insert/update
  }else{
    //delete
   }
}
```

Hope this will help you

Comment: But passing to my controller is no problem, checking them separately is..

if ($request->typedoc[1]){
                    //insert
                    
                }else{
                    //delete
                }

I do not want to make a list manually for each number...

Comment: Sorry, arrays are not my strongest point... found the solution!
In my controller:

$typedocs = $request->typedoc;
foreach ($typedocs as $key => $value){}

Comment: @user3370273 that's why you need to add some code with questions, this helps others to understand better.

Comment: Sorry. Thank you Hamalraj for your help!

Answer (score 0):

If you have 5 inputs, then you could do something like the following-

```
for($i=1;$i<=5;$i++){
    if($request->has('typedoc_'.$i)){
         $type = $request->input('typedoc_'.$i);
    } 
 }
```

Use request [has()](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/requests#retrieving-input) method to determine if a value is present on the `request`.

Or use `filled()` to determine if a value is `present` on the request and is not `empty`.

```
if ($request->filled('typedoc_'.$i)) {
    //insert/update
}
```